# Firebase 'child_added' DataSnapshot returns $id as name

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm trying to cycle through the items in a collection within my Firebase. Specifically a list references to another collection where the real data is held.

The URL looks like this: **`author / simplelogin:1 / posts`**

I have the following code in Angular that fires when each entry in loaded:

```
authorPosts.$on('child_added', function (post) {
  console.log(post.snapshot.name);
});
```

I have two entries:

```
>> my-first-post: "my-first-post"
>> my-second-post: "my-second-post"
```

Problem is the `child_added` event returns:

```
$id
my-first-post
my-second-post
```

With **$id** being unexpected and included only *sometimes*

For info I'm using:

- v1.0.15 Firebase
- v0.7.1 AngularFire
- v1.5.0 Firebase Simple Login
- v1.2.17 Angular (also tried v.1.3.0-beta.11)

Comment: Please include version info for Firebase, Angular, and AngularFire. Also, it is *AngularFire* that adds $id and not *Firebase*.

Comment: @Kato good point, I've added the versions of the libs I'm using

Comment: Is AngularFire adding it on purpose?

Comment: Indeed. The $id and $priority are added onto elements for reference. Angular 1.3.0 beta 11 introduced a breaking change to angular.fromJSON (it no longer strips of $ prefixed elements). I couldn't reproduce any state in which ids appear some of the time. Might need more context here.

Comment: Ok, I'll get the code into a position where I can upload it to GitHub and you can see what exactly is going on. I'll be back..